# Using fragment in NavigationTab sample of ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to make the TabNavigation Sample in ActionBarSherlock works with going to different fragment, not just change the text of a textView (as we have in this sample). This is my code:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestNavigation extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            SherlockFragment PlayerFragment = new PhotosActivity();
            tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(PlayerFragment));
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        public SherlockFragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(SherlockFragment fragment) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }   
     }
```

And main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And photoActivity is very simple:

```
public class PhotosActivity extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.photos_layout, container, false);
    }   
}
```

could you help me?

If you think I am in the wrong way, please give me some sample or toturial that I can follow.

Comment: whats the problem in there ?

Comment: It crashed. I couldn't make it work.

Comment: check the imports, are you importing ActionBar from sherlock for those tabs ? can you post your imports ?

Comment: Imports are at the top of the class. Do you know any sample in GitHub or any other toturial that can help me?

Comment: sherlock lib includes sample project you can use that, but i noticed something, maybe it is what make the problems, in your TestNavigation class you are extending sherlockActivity not sherlockFragmentActivity, that might be the problem, if not post the exception you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your activity to extends SherlockFragmentActivity not SherlockActivity
and one more thing is to move `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);` to `onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)` method and i don't think you need `ft.remove(fragment);` that is inside  `onTabReselected()` because it will remove your fragment if the tab is pressed while it is selected